# merge two json statements into one using matillion ETL for snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I want to combine these two JSON into one using matillion ETL for snowflake

JSON statement 1:

```
[{                                          
    "StepId": 1,
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
    "Parameter": 4,
    "Filter": "",
    "SortKey": "",
    "Skip": -1,                            
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
```

JSON statement 2:

```
{
        "ConditionId": 4,
        "Threshold": "37",
        "ActionPlan": 3,
        "TriggerAction": 5
}
```

the result I want:

```
[{                                          
    "StepId": 1,
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
    "Parameter": 4,
    "Filter": "",
    "SortKey": "",
    "Skip": -1,                            
    "ParameterFileGroup": 1,
    "ParameterGroup": 1,
{
        "ConditionId": 4,
        "Threshold": "37",
        "ActionPlan": 3,
        "TriggerAction": 5
}}
]
```

Comment: The result you want is not valid JSON  - so are you sure that's what you want to produce?

Comment: @NickW yeah it’s not a valid json! But the requirement is that I want to merge two json statements in matillion ETL for snowflake

Comment: So you want to create a column that contains the combined text of these 2 statements, rather than a valid JSON statement? If so, just use standard string manipulation techniques: concatenation, substring, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are in 2 columns: JSON1, JSON2.  Use the calculator component.  add a new calculation called: JSON3.  The calculation is: "JSON1" || '\r' || "JSON2" || '\r' || '}]'

[image]

Comment: I want the array ‘[‘ and ‘]’ to be included too

Comment: I added a CR so the output formats the way you are looking for:

Comment: "JSON1" || '\r' || "JSON2" || '\r' || '}]'